# Text formatting not working properly

Tags: php, html, css

Basically what I have is a discussion forum that takes comments from users.  It is taken from a textarea and put into a database.  when put into the database it looks like this:

```
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
```

When viewing the individual post it looks this:

```
This is a paragraph.
This is another paragraph.
```

When viewing the main page it looks like this:

```
This is a paragraph.This is another paragraph
```

What I'm wondering is how to make it so that the formatting is the same for both the individual post and the main page where the viewer can see multiple posts.  I'm using PHP if that helps at all.  Thanks!

Also, If it helps here's the php code I'm using to echo the text to the main page:

```
echo '<div style="padding:4px; style="font-size:9pt;"">';
        if (strlen($blogentryText) > 500) {
                $blogentryText = substr($blogentryText, 0, 500). '...<a href="'.WEBSITE.'projects/commercialize/pipeline/blog/view.php?id='.$blogentryID.'&project='.$coaching.'&cycle='.$cycle.'">[read more]</a>';
                    }
                echo $blogentryText;
            echo '</div>';
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't be storing HTML in your database. Then you would be able to format it based on context.

Comment: I think your are not generating your dynamic data within the paragraph. suggest you to share your PHP code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be allowing html tags to be inserted to your database, You will get hacked. If you want to keep the formatting you can use something like htmlentities() which will convert any html to its equal entity, ie: "<" becomes "&lt"; and ">" becomes "&gt";, (the semicolons go next to the end of those but I left them out otherwise you would only see a less than and greater than sign) Then when you display the page you use html_entity_decode()

encoding
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

decoding
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Paragraph tag always uses next line when two paragraphs are used as you mentioned... if on some page you are viewing both of

tags text in same line it means that there is some css applied on the paragraph tag that is overriding its default property of using the line place.. its not php or html issue.. it has to do with your CSS. Use firebug or chrome or something to check the CSS applied on the tag and remove it or use the same CSS on all pages so it looks the same.